# Windows Server 2003 folder redirect problem

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, folder-redirection

I have a small network with one Windows Server 2003 server, two Windows XP and one Windows Vista client.

The server is working fine, I am having problem in configuring folder redirection. I'm searching for this issue from last two days - but no success.

My ini file look like this:

```
[FolderStatus]
My Documents=11
My Pictures=2
Application Data=11
Desktop=11
[My Documents]
s-1-1-0=\\dataserver\common\%USERNAME%\My Documents
[My Pictures]
[Application Data]
s-1-1-0=\\dataserver\common\%USERNAME%\Application Data
[Desktop]
s-1-1-0=\\dataserver\common\%USERNAME%\Desktop
```

It works fine if we login to the Windows Server 2003 machine, but it's not working on Windows XP and Vista.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you use this guide to set up redirection? If not, I would suggest giving it a read.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739647(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Vista redirection requires a different GP, or creating/modifying the original GP from a machine w the new RSAT / Remote  Server Administration Tool if the DC isn't a Server 2008 machine.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766208%28WS.10%29.aspx

That doesn't explain why it fails on XP though, use GP Results wizard to test and make sure it's applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've already solved the issue but...

As it's a small network my first thought here is that the client machines can't resolve that path or that the users don't have appropriate permissions when browsing across the network.

I'd check that the share permissions aren't too restrictive and try to get to that path from the file explorer on one of the machines.

Does either the server or the client report any errors?

Answer (score 0):

s-1-1-0=\dataserver**common**\%USERNAME%\Application Data
[Desktop]
s-1-1-0=\dataserver**common**\%USERNAME%\Desktop

my solution:

look at the permission of your shared folder(Common). you must add the users group in that permission.

share the common folder and put a dollar($ ex. common$) sign at the end so that the shared folder will be hidden.